# Dividir array em grupos menores

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array nesse formato:

```
meuArray = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ...];
```

Gostaria de transformá-lo em um array multidimensional com javascript/jquery deixando-o assim:

```
meuArray = [
             [0] => ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"];
             [1] => ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
              ...
           ]
```

A quantidade de chaves por array irá variar, porém para facilitar a resposta, podemos considerar sempre 5 chaves por array.

Comment: Porque pode variar, então, a regra deveria ser melhor explicado, qual é a verdadeira regra de criar vários arrays a partir de um?

Comment: O corte será feito de acordo com a quantidade de resultados que couber na resolução do usuário, se for 5 vou cortar de 5 em 5 e criar uma linha com esses 5 e assim por diante

Comment: Se o número de item for 6 como é dividido?

Comment: Isso é o que eu quero saber, se for de 6 em 6, eu vou atualizar a divisão dentro do sucess e passar o loop que alguém irá me responder, vou testar com as respostas atuais pra ver se consigo o que quero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

- Percorreria os itens do `array`;
- Utilizaria uma variável para controlar o grupo em que o item será colocado;
- Incrementaria a variável caso o resto da divisão dela pelo máximo fosse 0. (No seu caso em 5, 10, ... 25, ...);

O resultado é o seguinte:

```js
var arrayBase = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var dados = [];

function separar(base, maximo) {
  var resultado = [[]];
  var grupo = 0;

  for (var indice = 0; indice < base.length; indice++) {
    if (resultado[grupo] === undefined) {
      resultado[grupo] = [];
    }

    resultado[grupo].push(base[indice]);

    if ((indice + 1) % maximo === 0) {
      grupo = grupo + 1;
    }
  }

  return resultado;
}

dados = separar(arrayBase, 5);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dados));
```

Com `ES6` utilizando `Math.floor`, `reduce` e `Sintaxe de Espalhamento`:

```js
const separar = (itens, maximo) => {
  return itens.reduce((acumulador, item, indice) => {
    const grupo = Math.floor(indice / maximo);
    acumulador[grupo] = [...(acumulador[grupo] || []), item];
    return acumulador;
  }, []);
};

// Teste de execução
const itens = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(separar(itens, 5)));
```

Comment: e para acessar os resultados obtidos?
Fiz isso dados = JSON.stringify(separar(5));
Porém quando tento acessar dados[0] não da em nada.

Comment: @LeoLetto `dados = separar(5);` O `JSON.stringify` é pra transformar em `string`

Comment: Essa função leva em consideração caso o meuArray tenha menos que 5 chaves? pois testei aqui e quando tem só 2 chaves por exemplo, ele retorna no array apenas das chaves obtidas no meuArray

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou do jeito que eu precisava :)

Comment: @LeoLetto Vou fazer uma leve alteração para que passe o array como parâmetro também. Fica mais útil.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar o método [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) que vai dividir o array com base no índice de início e final, iterando o array por um valor de corte, levando em conta que seu array pode possuir *n* tamanho total.

```js
var meuArray = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  , novoArray = []
  , corte = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < meuArray.length; i = i + corte) {
  novoArray.push(meuArray.slice(i, i + corte));
}

console.log(novoArray);
```

Mesmo se o array possuir outro tamanho ou corte diferente de 5, o novo array será cortado. O último array ficará com o resto dos elementos.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo você dar uma olhada no método push de Array: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Mas um exemplo bem básico seria assim:

```
meuArray = [];
meuArray.push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
meuArray.push([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

Ate a quantidade que vc precisar, recomendo usar um loop.

Answer (score 2):

Usando um laço de repetição simples, você pode usar o [Array.Slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) para separar o array e o [Array.Push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) para criar um novo com os elementos extraídos.

```js
function separarArray(arr, tamanho) {
  var novoArray = [];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    novoArray.push(arr.slice(i, i + tamanho));
    i += tamanho;
  }
  return novoArray;
}

console.log(separarArray(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"], 5));
```

Answer (score -3):

Caso use em vários pontos, sugiro adicionar protótipos de objetos.

```js
var splitList = function (list, limit) {
  var originalList = [];

  var loop = Number((list.length / limit).toFixed(0)) + (!!(list.length % limit) ? 1 : 0);
      
  for (var index = 0, position = limit; index < loop; index++, position += limit) {
    var grup = list.slice(index * limit, position);
    if (grup.length) originalList.push(grup);
  };

  return originalList;
};

console.log(splitList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4)); ///[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```