# Converter uma string separada por vírgula para array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, string

Tenho uma *string* dessa forma ...

```
var listAdd = "1789, 3, 8 , 1788, 3, 8, 1790, 3, 9"
```

Como converto em um *array* como abaixo?

```
[1789,3,8], [1788,3,8], [1790,3,9]
```

O código que estou tentando não está dando certo:

```
var ArrayAdd = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < listAdd.length; i++) {
                s = "";
                s = String(listAdd[i]);
                ArrayAdd.push(s);
            }
```

Comment: Você precisa criar um array a cada três posições? Ou tem algum outro critério?

Comment: É isso mesmo .... sem mais critérios!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dividir array em grupos menores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/dividir-array-em-grupos-menores)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí e nem dá para começar falar o que. Tem algumas formas de resolver isto, eu preferi assim, ainda que talvez não seja a mais eficiente (mas em geral o pessoal costuma propor, e sei que vão postar aqui até piores nesse ponto), mas precisaria testar porque sem usar o `split()` pode dar um ganho de um lado e perda de outro.

Precisa quebrar o texto em partes de acordo com a vírgula. Depois agrupar de 3 em 3 montando um novo *array* com cada grupo novo, se é que deu para entender.

Eu fiz inferindo critérios pela resposta esperada que foi postada, não existe isso de "sem mais critérios", se eles ficaram ambíguos pode não dar o resultado real que deveria dar porque o AP pode ter se equivocado em alguma coisa colocando o problema. Simples e performático:

```js
let texto = "1789, 3, 8 , 1788, 3, 8, 1790, 3, 9";
let array = new Array();
let quebrado = texto.split(",");
for (let i = 0; i < quebrado.length; i+= 3) array.push([parseInt(quebrado[i]), parseInt(quebrado[i + 1]), parseInt(quebrado[i + 2])]);
console.log(array);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/SplitGroup.js).

Comment: Obrigado! Perfeito!

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma de realizar a transformação necessária é seguir os seguintes passos:

- Usar a função `split` para separar os resultados por `,`;
- Executar a função `map` no `array` resultante para remover os espaços com `trim` e converter cada item para inteiro com `parseInt`;
- Utilizar a função proposta na resposta da pergunta [**Dividir array em grupos menores**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167538/59479) para dividir o `array` obtido anteriormente.

```js
const separar = (itens, maximo) => {
  return itens.reduce((acumulador, item, indice) => {
    const grupo = Math.floor(indice / maximo);
    acumulador[grupo] = [...(acumulador[grupo] || []), item];
    return acumulador;
  }, []);
};

const lista = '1789, 3, 8 , 1788, 3, 8, 1790, 3, 9';
const resultados = lista.split(',').map((item) => parseInt(item.trim(), 10));
console.log(separar(resultados, 3));
```

---

> [**String.prototype.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
>
> O método `split()` divide um objeto `String` em um `array` de `strings` ao separar a `string` em `substrings`.

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

---

> [**String.prototype.trim()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
>
> O método `trim()` remove os espaços em branco (whitespaces) do início e/ou fim de um texto. É considerado espaço em branco (espaço, tabulação, espaço fixo/rígido, etc.) e todo sinal de fim de linha de texto (`LF, CR`, etc.).

---

> [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
>
> A função `parseInt()` analisa um argumento `string` e retorna um inteiro na `base` especificada.

Answer (score 6):

A cada três virgulas substitui por `#`, depois separa por `#` e `,` convertendo para `Number`

```js
const str = '1789, 3, 8 , 1788, 3, 8, 1790, 3, 9';

let index = 0;

const result = str
    .replace(/[,]/g, _ => ++index % 3 === 0 ? '#' : ',')
    .split('#')
    .map(e => e.split(',').map(n => Number(n)));

console.log(result);
```